# Does Destiny + DLCs transfer over from PS3 to PS4?

Tags: destiny

In the next couple days, I am purchasing a PlayStation 4, so I can play with some buddies who all have Destiny on PlayStation 4.

I am aware that I can transfer character data over; but does digital game access transfer over, as well?

I have purchased all 3 DLCs. I have a physical copy of the core game, but it would be nice to know if I also did not have to repurchase that, too.

Comment: From what I have read, it seems like _digital_ DLC will transfer between gens, though you will need to buy a PS4 version of the base Destiny game. Maybe [this help article](https://www.bungie.net/en/Help/Article/12122) will help you out.

Comment: I would still highly suggest asking this question when you purchase your PS4 if you are buying it from a GameStop or the like, as they will generally be able to give you the most up to date information.

Comment: I have included the provision for the actual game, in your question. I see almost identical versions of this question, and the answers all directly answer to the entire game; not just the DLC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Around the time when destiny came out, there was a limited time offer for people to get Destiny on the next gen consoles, along with a free DLC transfer. So far as I have seen, that was only for people who got the digital version of Destiny for the PS3 or 360. This happened around January 2015. The only way to get DLC from the PS3 to PS4 is if it is cross-platform.

I hope this helped, if you have more questions about Destiny on the PS4 ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, they do not transfer. I, like you originally had destiny for ps3, then later transferred to ps4. When later I tried to play on ps3 I was unable to access the dlc content. Also when I went to the PlayStation store to try to download the dlc, I wouldn't let me as it is "only downloadable on ps4 system". So no it does not transfer.

Comment: That's strange because I got my dlc content automatically downloaded. I was able to actually access the content after I subscribed to play station plus. This is unfortunate because now I have to pay for destiny online but I was able to transfer it all over.

Comment: @ThomasLittler, it is worth noting that only interaction-based missions should require +; missions that do not take you to matchmaking can be played as single player, on xbone, without gold (Xbox version of PS+)